# Relationship between lightlike and spatial compactification

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

The compactification of a spatial dimension, say $x^1$ given by the identification $x \sim x^1 + 2\pi R$ is said to be related to the lightlike compactification by a Lorentz boost :

$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    x^0 \\
    x^1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\sim
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    x^0 \\
    x^1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
+2\pi
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    -R \\
    R \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$$

What exactly is the relationship between them? How can I see this? And what does it mean from a physics point of view?

Comment: What source are you reading from?

Comment: @Dimension10 yes, I have seen it thanks :-). Obviously such questions are not popular enough to get more votes (ambiguity of this sentence intented :-P ...). Yep it is mostly about the Lorentz transformations and the application of the issue in matrix/string theory is interesting too.

Comment: @Dilaton: Uh...  for all I know,  the application in string theory is just getting Type IIA from M-theory compactified on a light - like circle . . . Don't know if there are other applications.